Are soldiers sinning when they kill enemy in a war?
Soldiers are like slaves to their commanders and have to do whatever they are told to do. If not, in war war-like situation, they can be punished by their commanders. So will the soldiers be accountable for the killing they do?
The question came to mind because of the recent war in Gaza. The Israelis who are fighting Palestinians are doing so because they have to do compulsory military service, so even if they dislike killing people, they are compelled to do so.
Note: I have asked the same question in the Islam section also. Actually, Muslims and Jews are brothers who are descended from our patriarch Abraham (Peace be upon him), It is sad to see them fighting each other, I feel like they are forced to fight each other by some who have a vested interest in this conflict.

Hi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this question. I can foresee that this question is going to be hard to answer in practical situations here. All we can do is answer the theory, and I can see 2 possibilities: the situation where a Jew is drafted to an army to fight a war that is not a mitzva, and one where he is fighting in a war that is a mitzva. It seems you are asking about the first - could you edit and clarify that (ideally by removing the specific example and explaining directly) to avoid getting the wrong answers

@Shafeek - I think your question is discussing whether the compulsory military service absolves an individual soldier from personal responsibility, similar to the Nurenberg defence. Considering the politically charged context of the question which invokes strong emotions on both sides, it may be conducive to edit the question to be strictly theoretical.

@RabbiKaii - Perhaps equally important to clarify is whether the question is about legitimate military targets, or unfortunate civilian casualties.

The question contains several conditionals that make it hard to properly answer the question (the question is a compound in a sense). The fundamental claim underlying the question, which needs to be addressed, is  whether soldiers can (legally) be regarded as slaves, conditionally followed by the question of their then individual responsibility. But this is built upon an implicit premisse that the context described is about murdering (immorally) rather than killing (morally defensibly). Can the question be refined to prevent having to address three seperate claims/questions?

Soldiers are supposed to kill the enemy in a war. They'd be sinning if they didn't.

I voted to close the question because it does not appear to be about Judaism but rather Israeli politics. Jewish Halacha only applies to wars waged by a Davidic monarch which we didn't have for some 2500 years. In other cases, Jews, like any other humans, have the right to defend themselves.

The Maharal of Prague, 16th-century commentator, writes:

The Torah allows war when we are attacked, and in responding, we are allowed to not distinguish between the guilty and the innocent. [Gur Aryeh to Gen. 34:13]

However, warning may be given.  The Torah says:

When you approach a town to attack it, you shall offer it terms of peace.
[Deuteronomy 20:10]

In commenting, the Midrash tells us:

Rav Shmuel bar Naḥman said: What did Joshua do [when he was about to enter the Promised Land]? He would publish an edict in every place [of the Land of Canaan] he went to conquer, on which he wrote: “Whoever wants to go, let him go; whoever wants to make peace with us, let him make peace; and whoever wants to make war shall make war.”

-The Girgashites vacated and departed from there, and the Holy One, blessed be He, gave them a land as beautiful as their native land, namely Africa.
-The Gibeonites desired to make peace with Israel, and Joshua made peace with them.
-However, the 31 Canaanite kings came to battle with Joshua, and the Holy One blessed be He caused them to fall.
[Deut. Rabbah 5:14]

For balance, consider adding Tanchuma Lech Lecha 19 about how despite the fact we are allowed to not distinguish between the guilty and innocent, we are very scared to kill anyone truly innocent. You might also want to explain why we are allowed to not distinguish, and the limits of that (white flag, surrender, etc)

The Talmud notes:
Once permission has been granted to an angel to destroy, it does not distinguish between righteous and wicked. [Bava Kamma 60a]
Thus, the default position is that the innocent perish with the guilty.  Indeed, before the Exodus, we had to distinguish ourselves from the Egyptians to prevent our own firstborn from dying.  Also, Abraham had to ask God to save Sodom and Gomorrah for the sake of the righteous in it. [Gen. 18:23-32]  It was not an automatic thing.

That's angel/din mechanics. We are talking about halacha
